# Kernel mode driver won't link in VS 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, kmdf

I have a KMD that uses the Platform toolset WindowsKernelModeDirver8.1.
The driver compiles links, and runs without any problems using VS 2013.
I am running Windows 10.

When I try to compile it with VS 2015 I get the following link error.

1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol GsDriverEntry
1>terVertaPci.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie referenced in function terVertaPciDevCtl
1>ntoskrnl.lib(gshandler.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie
1>terVertaPci.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __security_cookie referenced in function terVertaPciDevCtl

I can't find references to the unresolved symbols any where in my c++ code.
It appears that VS 2015 is linking in different libraries than VS 2013 but
I can't find any information about what the differences are. My organization has
declared VS 2015 as the new standard which is why I am encountering this problem.

I'm a novice in dealing with KMD code. Any help would be appreciated.

---

When I first open the solution in VS 2015, I am informed that VC++ Compiler and Libraries need to be upgraded, but the results of the automatic upgrade are:

```
Configuration 'Win7 Debug|x64': no upgrade required. Platform Toolset is 'WindowsKernelModeDriver8.1'.
Configuration 'Win7 Release|x64': no upgrade required. Platform Toolset is 'WindowsKernelModeDriver8.1'.
TargetFrameworkVersion = v4.5 (was v4.5)
```

Retargeting End: 1 completed, 0 failed, 0 skipped

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2015 only works with WDK for Windows 10, version 1703.
                    it does not work with WindowsKernelModeDriver 8.1 even
                    though 8.1 is an option in PlatformToolset.

The VS 2015 upgrade tool was incorrect when it said "no upgrade required"

Installing WDK for Windows 10, version 1703 and setting the PlatformToolset
as WindowsKernelModeDriver 10.0 solves the problem.